# Does docker-in-docker use memory or disk?

Tags: linux, docker, out-of-memory, diskspace

I am trying to build a docker image inside docker (docker-in-docker, dind). The image is very large and it is failing to build with the error `no space left on device`.

Setup:
I am running this on the teamcity agent docker image, with the docker-in-docker configuration

Does my host machine need more memory or more disk space? Does docker-in-docker build in memory or on disk?

Comment: when you get no space left on device issue in docker.that is related to your host machine space.

Comment: `df -h` disk space usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses disk.

A thorough explanation of how and why docker-in-docker works is in this [article](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

I originally asked this question with Teamcity's agent in mind, but I wanted to generalize the question. It seems that it is the industry standard never actually run docker-in-docker because it can cause data corruption, and most use cases can be solved with a docker-to-docker solution (explained below). Nevertheless, the nearly-docker-in-docker implementations are still referred to as docker-in-docker in some CI documentation even if it is not a true docker-in-docker solution.

The docker-to-docker workaround, generally, is to expose the host docker daemon to the container in a volume mount, i.e. `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...` And if you expose the daemon to a container, or expose the `dind` image to another container, in both cases the docker engine is running at the host level or as a container in the first level of docker, meaning that it uses disk.

Hope this clarifies.